# Do collections convert int to integers sometimes?

Tags: java

I was reading somewhere that even if I use int primitives, adding them to certain types of collections may result in a conversion from int to integers.

When is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java collections can only contain objects.  Therefore, all collections will [Autobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) any primitive types you pass them into their equivalent object (boxed) form before storing them.  So `int` primitives will be converted to `Integer`s before being stored in a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Java generics and  require their type to be a full-fledged object, which primitives obviously aren't.  Note that collections before generics were introduced worked with `Object`s, so they also required full-fledged objects.  Java also introduced auto-boxing and auto-unboxing to make this requirement less of a pain, that means that when you pass an `int` where a method expects an `Integer`, an appropriate `Integer` will automatically be created with the correct value.

Comment: Collections required wrapper objects even before generics were supported so your starting explanation is misleading

Comment: @Pangea As they were (and still are) declared to work with `Object`s, I'd have thought that was self-evident, but I've added it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It is called [auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) and **all** collections does this *since Java 5*. It is from `int` primitive to `java.lang.Integer` wrapper class (not integers as you mentioned in your post).

Answer (score 0):

The Java [guide on autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) says about this:

> ... you can’t put an int (or other primitive value) into a collection. Collections can only hold object references, so you have to box
>   primitive values into the appropriate wrapper class

Answer (score 0):

Since the JDK's collections maintain data as `java.lang.Object` references (or Object arrays) internally, they all do have to store the values in boxed/wrapped form.

If you do want to reduce the memory footprint for specialized collections, consider using [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), which has specialized implementations that store data in primitive arrays.